# org.dozer.MappingException: No read or write method found for field

Tags: java, xml, mapping, pojo, dozer

i have one source pojo class inside which it is referring another pojo class and it is in chain and i m getting the above error.

my code is

```
List myMappingFiles = new ArrayList();
             myMappingFiles.add("dozerMapping.xml");
            // myMappingFiles.add("someOtherDozerBeanMappings.xml");
             DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
             mapper.setMappingFiles(myMappingFiles);
             mapper.map(gsrlObject,temp, "a");
```

my dozermapping.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
<mapping map-id="a"> 
    <class-a>com.dnb.dsc.ihx.bom.GSRL</class-a>
    <class-b>com.ihx.model.Subj</class-b>   
    <field>
    <a>gsrlObject.GSRLMSGSRQV1a.SUBJUPDTRNRQList[0].SUBJUPDRQList[0].INVTDATAList[0].PAYLHDR.SUBJID</a>
    <b>subjId</b>
    </field> 
  </mapping>  
  </mappings>
```

any help regarding this

thanks

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.dozer.MappingException: No read or write method found for field (gsrlObject.GSRLMSGSRQV1a.SUBJUPDTRNRQList[0].SUBJUPDRQList[0].INVTDATAList[0].PAYLHDR.SUBJID) in class (class com.dnb.dsc.ihx.bom.GSRL)
 at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.determinePropertyType(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:291)
 at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:66)

Comment: at org.dozer.fieldmap.FieldMap.getSrcFieldType(FieldMap.java:121)
 at org.dozer.loader.MappingsParser.processMappings(MappingsParser.java:99)
 at org.dozer.loader.CustomMappingsLoader.load(CustomMappingsLoader.java:65)
 at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadCustomMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:213)
 at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.getMappingProcessor(DozerBeanMapper.java:186)
 at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:97)
 at com.ihx.util.ReadIHXFile.main(ReadIHXFile.java:73)

Answer (score 1):

It means the **dozerMapping.xml** attributes has been Mismatched or the attribute is not present in the entity class.

Comment: This answer was useful for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, Dozer can't map your source path into a method:

```
gsrlObject.GSRLMSGSRQV1a.SUBJUPDTRNRQList[0].SUBJUPDRQList[0].INVTDATAList[0].P‌​AYLHDR.SUBJID
```

Without seeing the full structure of all the objects its hard to say which part if causing the problem, but at a guess, i'm going to say: gsrlObject is an instance of the the GSRL class, in which case take this one out and it may work. Try adding each part of the source path in 1 piece at a time to see which part of the mapping is causing the problem.